# Can I just use Dialogfow's default fulfillment webhook code as a starting place on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, dialogflow-es

I am developing a webhook in Node.js for my Fullfillment piece in Google's Dialogflow.  I will host the webhook on Azure.

My question is can I just take/use the default webhook/fullfillment code that's in Dialogflow and copy it / host it on Azure and use it as a starting place?  What about the segment of code "exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)?

```
    'use strict';

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    function welcome(agent) {
        agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
    }

    function fallback(agent) {
        agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
        agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
    }

        agent.add(`Thank you...`);

        return admin.database().ref('AgeInfo').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        var averageAge = snapshot.child("RunningAverage").val();
        agent.add(`Our recorded average age is ` + averageAge);
        });
    }


    // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    intentMap.set('AskAge', handleAge);
    // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
    // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an express-like service on Azure, you shouldn't have too many problems. There are two things you'll need to do

1. Setup the `body-parser` middleware for your express app which will convert the JSON text body into an object and store it in `request.body`.
2. Replace the `exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(` portion with the express routing for a POST request to "/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment" (or pick a different name, as I did below - you just need to change the URL for your webhook).

I haven't tested, but it might look something like this:

```
var expressApp = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

expressApp.use( bodyParser.json() );

expressApp.post( '/dialogflowFulfillment', (request, response) => {
  // Continue with the rest of the code here that was inside the
  // onRequest handler
```

Comment: I was planning on using a server-less function on Azure.  Would I still need to use express?

Comment: I don't know the details of how their serverless functions work. If they provide access to a request-like object with an object body and a response-like object, it should, tho in either case you may need to do additional work to make it work.